# Broken return/enter key - how to start blockout without it

Tags: keyboard

I have a laptop with a non-functioning return/enter key using Windows XP. Most things work well without an enter key these days, but I cannot start blockout which opens a window and asks for an enter input to start the game.

What is the simplest way to send an "enter" signal to the game to make it start?

Comment: How did you type this without an enter key?

Comment: That is an excellent question @Mikhail...

Comment: I always copy a carriage return from somewhere and paste it where needed. However, this does not work with programs like blockout that require an enter signal in a window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download a program like [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/), this will allow you to map a different key or key-combination to simulate the "enter" button.